# GetAsyncKeyState - called every millisecond

Tags: vb.net, api, keyboard

I have a really annoying problem. I use GetAsyncKeyState() to determine if a key was pressed or not. Unfortunately, that event fires as long as I hold down a key. Is there any way to check if a Key was released?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the Events from VB.NET.

For example the Form.KeyUp Event, KeyUp triggers only if the Key is going from State Down to Up again.

Also make sure that your form's KeyPreview property is set to true.